# update pandas column with another column's values using .loc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I need to conditionally update ColY below if the value for ColX != 0.  The difference to other examples is that I need ColY to be replaced by the values from ColX, as opposed to a string

I can replace with a string using .loc  when I use the following code:

`df1.loc[df1.ColX != 0, 'ColY'] = 'Example'`

How can I replace the relevant ColY values with the values from ColX? I have tried things such as the below to no avail

`df1.loc[df1.ColX != 0, 'ColY'] = df1.ColX`

My original dataframe, df1, is:

```
ID  ColX   ColY
A   2024   0
B   0      2023
C   2019   0
D   2023   2024
```

My desired output is:

```
ID  ColX   ColY
A   2024   2024
B   0      2023
C   2019   2019
D   2023   2023
```

Comment: Do you perse want to use `.loc` or are you open for other suggestions?

Comment: Your code `df1.loc[df1.ColX != 0, 'ColY'] = df1.ColX

` works fine unless you have duplicate index or it is category data

Comment: @BENY what happens if the index has duplicates? doesn't `.loc` update the values by only applying the same boolean mask  `df1.ColX != 0` on `df.ColX` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for your convenience, here's another *cleaner* method in my opinion, using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
df['ColY'] = np.where(df['ColX'].ne(0), df['ColX'], df['ColY'])

print(df)
  ID  ColX  ColY
0  A  2024  2024
1  B     0  2023
2  C  2019  2019
3  D  2023  2023
```

Comment: when you consider np.where, you can always using df.where in pandas :-)

Comment: I've seen it, just not sure if its using the same vectorized code under the hood? Is it the same? @Wen-Ben . I use `np.where` because I can be assured of its speed.

Comment: .where in pandas can apply on change to whole dataframe row , for example , you want to change all columns to the last column in df , using where is better :-)

Comment: Thanks Erfan.  I have tried this, and .where was something I had also considered, but I receive the following error:  TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable.  I assume this is a reference to the df['ColY'] within the call to .where

Comment: Are you using `np.where` or `df.where`. Because theres a difference. The code I provided runs correctly if you apply it correctly. @user2845013

Comment: Apologies, I had been using df.where, as advised, but had another issue.  This is fixed now.  Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `df1.loc[df1.ColX != 0, 'ColY'] = df1.ColX` is that you're trying to replace a subset of `df1.ColY`(i.e. where `df1.ColX != 0`) with the entire `df1.ColX`, which has more values.

To copy the correct values conditionally, you also have to apply the same filter to `df1.ColX`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[2024, 0], [0, 2023], [2019, 0], [2023, 2023],], columns=['ColX', 'ColY'])

relevant_cols = (df1.ColX != 0)
df1.loc[relevant_cols, 'ColY'] = df1.loc[relevant_cols, 'ColX']
df1
#   ColX  ColY
# 0  2024  2024
# 1     0  2023
# 2  2019  2019
# 3  2023  2023
```

Comment: He do not need write the condition twice